# How to toggle a specific class set

Tags: jquery, class, toggle, range

I have a range of classes:

- classA
- classB
- classC

and I have a `<span class='fixedClass'>` which needs to be toggled between one of these classes depending on a specific condition. You might say to use [jQuery toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

However my span has already other class attached to it which needs to stay always.

What's fastest and shortest code in jQuery to do this?

Comment: `addClass` keeps your current classes and adds new one's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample may help you: http://jsfiddle.net/e9bj5/

```
$(function(){

 $('.fixedClass').on("click", function() {

    var box = $(this);

    if ( box.hasClass('red') ) {
        box.removeClass('red').addClass('green');
    }
    else if ( box.hasClass('green') ) {
        box.removeClass('green').addClass('blue');
    }
    else if ( box.hasClass('blue') ) {
        box.removeClass('blue').addClass('red');
    }

 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this answer in combination with a for-loop would be best thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just go for changing the attribute **"class"** of your span, with `.attr()`
Check below code

```
function(newClassName){
$('.fixedClass').attr('class',newClassName +' fixedClass');
}
```

Comment: This solution is much shorter and thats what I like about it, however it is not working well when other classes during runtime are added to it.